# Nginx - shorter "expires" for args match

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using rewrite like this

```
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/(en|ga)?/?(.*)$ /index2.php?cultureKey=$1&mq=$2 last;
    }
```

but after I need certain rewritten URLs to be cached for 30 seconds. Remaining fast_cgi requests should be 5 minutes.

```
    fastcgi_cache_valid   200 302  5m;

    expires 5m;
    if ($args ~* (dynamic\.html)){
        expires 30s;
    }
```

I have tried moving those around, but either both dynamic.html and other files are still cached after 30 seconds or they both expire after 30.

How to make dynamic.html (rewritten) cached for 30s and remaining files for 5m?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$args` is a variable containing the request parameters on a `GET`, are you sure you are not after `$request_uri` or `$uri`? Maybe using a location block is better:

```
location ~* dynamic.html {
    expires 30s
}
```

but it depends on the rest of your config so YMMV.

Comment: how exactly config works? if i specify expires twice, which one is used?

Comment: and i have $args _after_ rewrite.

Comment: From what I know from Nginx configuration, the most specific applies before the broader, so I think that the 30s rule will apply to the ones that match the location and the others will be matched by the outside expires of 5m, but I can't find any documentation to back me there. About your other question, you should read [this](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#location) and [this](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) on nginx docs to understand.

Comment: missing a semicolon

Answer (score 1):

I think it is 'if' what causing problems. You should read this http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil